# AWS SAM local invoke doesn't work when python venv has dependencies

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I am trying to run a very simple python lambda function locally to learn how AWS SAM local invoke works and test my code.

I have a very simple file structure that more or less looks like this:

```
|- env/
|- lambda_function.py
|- pyproject.toml
|- setup.cfg
|- template.yaml
|- test_data.json
```

My lambda_function.py looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    print(pd.DataFrame({'c1': [1, 2, 3]}))
    return {}
```

My `template.yaml` looks like the following:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Resources:
  MyFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
```

And my setup.cfg defines the dependencies of my lambda, which at the moment is just `pandas`. I have pandas installed in my virtual env and it lives inside `env/lib/site-packages/...`

However, whenever I run the following:

```
sam local invoke -e ./test_data.json
```

I get the following error:

```
Invoking lambda_function.lambda_handler (python3.8)
Skip pulling image and use local one: amazon/aws-sam-cli-emulation-image-python3.8:rapid-1.27.2.

Mounting /Users/XXXXXXXX/XXXXXX/XXXXXXX/[current folder] as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
START RequestId: 10680278-8001-4a51-87a5-d5fa8a2ab2c6 Version: $LATEST
Traceback (most recent call last): Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pandas'
END RequestId: 10680278-8001-4a51-87a5-d5fa8a2ab2c6
REPORT RequestId: 10680278-8001-4a51-87a5-d5fa8a2ab2c6  Init Duration: 0.18 ms  Duration: 130.39 ms     Billed Duration: 200 ms Memory Size: 128 MB     Max Memory Used: 128 MB     
{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pandas'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "stackTrace": []}%
```

(I have X'd out some personal info) How do I get the SAM CLI to recognise the dependencies in the virtual env?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a layer to the Lambda function for it to work with pandas and other libraries.

1. Download the last awswrangler-layer zip file from the
   [aws-github-repo](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler/releases).
2. In AWS-Lambda-Layers create a layer and upload the zip file.
3. Add the layer to the lambda function.

Here is a [video](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/streaming-data-with-aws-kinesis-and-lambda/going-serverless?ex=7) of the process.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to use venv and sam together but I don't think this is how they're supposed to be used.

When you run `sam build` all packages in your `requirements.txt` are placed in `.aws-sam/build/my-app`. They aren't installed globally or in your virtual environment. For this reason when you run `sam local invoke` sam can't see any of your venv packages like pandas.

```
MyFunction/
├── app
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── lambda_function.py
│   └── ...
└── .aws-sam/
    ├── build/
    │   └── MyFunction/
    │       ├── lambda_function.py
    │       ├── pandas/
    │       ├── boto3/
    │       └── ...
    ├── build.toml
    └── build.zip
```

See here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/using-sam-cli-build.html